# Is Lupin III: A Woman Named Mine Fujiko a prequel or a reboot of the Lupin series?

Tags: lupin-the-third

I've watched *Lupin III: Mine Fujiko to Iu Onna* ("A Woman Named Mine Fujiko") and some scattered episodes of the original *Lupin III* TV series. One thing that isn't clear to me is how the two series are related.

Depending on who I ask, some say that the new series is a prequel which describes how Lupin's gang got together, while others say that it is a reboot with a different continuity. I haven't seen enough of the original series to judge this either way.

Is there any authoritative source which confirms the relationship between the two series, one way or the other?

Comment: I think it's both. Especially with the change in style and themes (and the retcons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as far as the timeline goes, it's obviously *before* the events of all 3 Lupin III TV series. Because of the lack of overall plot, it's hard to say whether or not events from "A woman named Fujiko Mine" match up with all the events in the TV series without any ret-conning, maybe with the exception that Fujiko has memory loss.

There's never been any official announcement as it being a prequel and it's not consistent with the source material where the first meeting(s) between Lupin and Fujiko in the manga differ from this series (not that there's much consistency between the manga and any of the TV series to begin with).

Likewise, because of inconsistencies within the TV series itself (different characterizations of Lupin between the red and green jackets, different characterizations of his sidekicks and Fujiko) you could say the Fujiko series was a reboot just as likely as Lupin III, part 2 and part 3, the manga, were all reboots. But if you want to consider them all within the same continuity, I don't see any reason not to include Fujiko's series as a prequel, even if there would need to be some ret-conning (can easily just say Fujiko lost her memory *again*).